# Can't compile with MinGW - libmpc-2.dll is missing

Tags: windows-vista, mingw

I have installed MinGW in Windows Vista, so I can use `gcc` but it doesn't work.

When I try to compile a `.c` file like `gcc hello.c -o hello.exe` I get an error (translated):

> cc1.exe: could not find libmpc-2.dll

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this file into the directory where your gcc executable can be found (the one named bin).
http://www38.zippyshare.com/v/95754574/file.html

The strange thing is that the MinGW installation of mine included this dll correctly.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I installed MinGW on a Windows XP yesterday and it worked fine, but this was Windows Vista. It's strange.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Installing the mpc package with `mingw-get` solved it for me.

1. Open a command line window
2. Go to your MinGW\bin directory: e.g. `cd MinGW\bin`
3. execute: `mingw-get install mpc`

Answer (score 3):

I have today same problem in Windows 7. All DLL's was in folder with MinGW. Only copying DLL's in SYSTEM32 folder solved this