# MinGW gcc -> libmpc-3.dll missing on 64-Bit Windows 7

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

I am using MinGW under a 64-Bit Windows 7. To compile my simple application I use the call:

`gcc -o main.exe main.c`

Then I get an Error that my `libmpc-3.dll` is missing. I already set my PATH variable to the `bin` dir of MinGW (there are only a `libmpc-2.dll` and a `libmpc-10.dll`.)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that the correct way to solve this and make MinGW install the right version of the library is using the `mingw-get` tool by calling it like `mingw-get install mpc`.

If anyone else is missing libmpc-3.dll for non MinGW related situations, seems that Cygwin has a package with `libmpc-3` (http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/windows/cygwin/x86_64/release/cygwin32-libmpc/).

Comment: I'm gonna give this a try, even tho I kind have a bad feeling to use this release. Also I got it running with "Mingw-builds" - I actually don't know whats the difference because it also uses the `gcc 4.8.1.` and it also doesn't come with the `libmpc-3` ...?

Comment: Also any chance it is a x64 issue - maybe the MinGW installation did include the libmpc but put it in the wrong dll folder? Maybe try 32bit cmd or something? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127446/cant-compile-with-mingw-libmpc-2-dll-is-missing Here a person states that `mingw-get` fixes this, mayne that is worth a shot.

Comment: That actually worked!!! - The problem was that I only used the graphical interface from mingw-get - there it showed me that it had already installed the `libmpc` - calling it from commandline with the command ``mingw-get install mpc` installed the correct library! Thank you! If you edit ur question and add the answer I can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks, edited the response, left the Cygwin package name in case anyone stumbles on this with a non MinGW related issue.

Comment: Download link is broken

Comment: In the Cygwin Setup in Windows, the missing package is found as "libmpc3" , not "libmpc-3".