# Program won't start because libmpc-3.dll is missing

Tags: c++, notepad++, mingw

I'm trying to compile c++ code in Notepad++. The command I'm running is as follows in the `Program to Run` box.

```
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -o "$(NAME_PART)" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

I get the error saying "The program can't start because libmpc-3.dll is missing...". I checked the MinGW file path and the libmpc-3.dll file is there in the bin folder.

Why would it say the file is missing, or is there something wrong with my command?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this solved question:

[MinGW gcc -> libmpc-3.dll missing on 64-Bit Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026973/mingw-gcc-libmpc-3-dll-missing-on-64-bit-windows-7)

Maybe it helps you.