# CMaker Missing DLL Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to build a project using CMake 3.4.0-rc3 on 64-bit Windows 8.

When I click "generate", I get an error saying:

[image]

Thing is, when I go to C:\MinGW\bin I do have a dll called libmpc-3.dll. By looking [at a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127446/cant-compile-with-mingw-libmpc-2-dll-is-missing) I tried running `mingw-get install mpc` which ran successfully but didn't fix the problem. Any advice? :)

EDIT: CMakeLists.txt

```
#
# Root vxl
#
#   vxl-maintainers@lists.sf.net

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.5)

# Support for CMake 2.6
IF( COMMAND CMAKE_POLICY )
  CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0003 NEW)
ENDIF( COMMAND CMAKE_POLICY )

# CMake 2.8 stuff
SET( CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0 ) # Remove when CMake >= 2.8.4 is required

# Use @rpath on OS X
IF( POLICY CMP0042 )
  CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0042 NEW)
ENDIF()

PROJECT(vxl)

SET( LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/lib CACHE PATH
     "Output directory for the vxl libraries" )

IF( NOT EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH )
    SET( EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "." )
ENDIF( NOT EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH )


# CMake support directory.
SET(VXL_CMAKE_DIR ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/config/cmake/Modules)

INCLUDE( ${VXL_CMAKE_DIR}/VXLStandardOptions.cmake )
INCLUDE( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/config/cmake/config/vxl_utils.cmake )
# INCLUDE( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/UseSTLPort.cmake )
INCLUDE(${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/config/cmake/doxygen/doxygen.cmake)

# Copy the UseVXL.cmake file to the binary directory so that client
# projects don't need to find the source directory first. They can run
# the UseVXL.cmake from the vxl binary directory, and determine the
# vxl source directory by loading the cache.
CONFIGURE_FILE( ${VXL_CMAKE_DIR}/UseVXL.cmake
                ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/UseVXL.cmake COPYONLY )

# Copy CTestCustom.cmake to top of build tree
CONFIGURE_FILE( ${VXL_CMAKE_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake
  ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/CTestCustom.cmake COPYONLY )

# Location of VXL's FindXXX.cmake CMake modules.
# This is identical to VXL_CMAKE_DIR.  Perhaps we should eliminate MODULE_PATH?
SET( MODULE_PATH ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/config/cmake/Modules CACHE STATIC "VXL module path" )

# For use in client projects that call UseVXL.cmake
SET (VXL_LIBRARY_PATH ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH} CACHE STATIC "Where all the vxl libraries are, for clients to use." )

# Options to add extra compiler and linker flags
#
# These options allow you to specify additional flags without
# affecting the default flags for a particular platform or build type.
# This is especially useful for adding extra warning flags.
SET( VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_C_FLAGS             CACHE STRING "Extra flags appended to CMAKE_C_FLAGS" )
SET( VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           CACHE STRING "Extra flags appended to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS" )
SET( VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    CACHE STRING "Extra flags appended to CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS" )
SET( VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS CACHE STRING "Extra flags appended to CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS" )
SET( VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS CACHE STRING "Extra flags appended to CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS" )
SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS             "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS           "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS    "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${VXL_EXTRA_CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS}" )


# Option to specify whether this is a build for the dashboard.  Each
# dashboard build should set BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD to YES in the
# initial cache (set in the CTest script).
OPTION( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD "Is this a build for the dashboard?" NO )

# A variable to default some OPTIONs to YES for the dashboard, but to
# NO for other builds.
IF( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )
  SET( YES_FOR_DASHBOARD "YES" )
ELSE( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )
  SET( YES_FOR_DASHBOARD "NO" )
ENDIF( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )

# Use this variable in vxl_config.h to tell if it is a shared build
set(VXL_BUILD_SHARED FALSE)
if(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  set(VXL_BUILD_SHARED TRUE)
endif()

# Do platform-specific configuration.
IF(NOT VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)
  SUBDIRS(config/cmake/config)
ENDIF(NOT VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)


# Options to reduce build to just some core libraries
OPTION( BUILD_CORE_NUMERICS "Build VXL's numerics libraries" YES )
OPTION( BUILD_CORE_SERIALISATION "Build VXL's serialisation libraries" YES )
OPTION( BUILD_CORE_UTILITIES "Build VXL's utility libraries" YES )
OPTION( BUILD_CORE_GEOMETRY "Build VXL's geometry libraries" YES )
OPTION( BUILD_CORE_IMAGING "Build VXL's imaging libraries" YES )
OPTION( BUILD_NONDEPRECATED_ONLY "Build only nondeprecated libraries (Experimental)" NO )
IF(BUILD_CORE_NUMERICS)
  IF( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )
    OPTION( BUILD_CORE_PROBABILITY "Build VXL's probability libraries (Experimental)" YES )
  ELSE( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )
    OPTION( BUILD_CORE_PROBABILITY "Build VXL's probability libraries (Experimental)" NO )
  ENDIF( BUILD_FOR_VXL_DASHBOARD )
ENDIF(BUILD_CORE_NUMERICS)
SET (BUILD_CORE_ALL OFF CACHE INTERNAL "All Core libraries are being built")
IF (BUILD_CORE_GEOMETRY AND BUILD_CORE_NUMERICS)
  IF (BUILD_CORE_UTILITIES AND BUILD_CORE_SERIALISATION)
    IF (BUILD_CORE_IMAGING)
      SET (BUILD_CORE_ALL ON CACHE INTERNAL "All Core libraries are being built")
    ENDIF (BUILD_CORE_IMAGING)
  ENDIF (BUILD_CORE_UTILITIES AND BUILD_CORE_SERIALISATION)
ENDIF (BUILD_CORE_GEOMETRY AND BUILD_CORE_NUMERICS)

# Optionally use old error reporting methods, rather than exceptions.
# The main use is in vil which often uses/used null images to imply an error.
OPTION (VXL_LEGACY_ERROR_REPORTING "Use old error reporting methods rather than exceptions?" YES)
IF (VXL_LEGACY_ERROR_REPORTING)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS( -DVXL_LEGACY_ERROR_REPORTING )
ENDIF (VXL_LEGACY_ERROR_REPORTING)



# Options to build no longer maintained libraries.
# It is still useful to have the dashboard check that they are correct,
# but no-one is likely to work on improving test coverage or fixing memory leaks.
OPTION( BUILD_UNMAINTAINED_LIBRARIES "Build libraries that are no longer actively maintained?" ${YES_FOR_DASHBOARD} )

# Option to build Windows Unicode support, the string
# type of which is wchar_t, each character is a 16-bit unsigned integer.
IF(WIN32)
  IF(VXL_HAS_WIN_WCHAR_T)
    OPTION( VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T "Build overloading functions that accept Windows wide char strings?" YES )
    IF(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T)   # Force it to be 0/1
      SET(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T 1)
    ELSE(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T)
      SET(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T 0)
    ENDIF(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T)
  ELSE(VXL_HAS_WIN_WCHAR_T)
    SET(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T 0)
  ENDIF(VXL_HAS_WIN_WCHAR_T)
ELSE(WIN32)
  # avoid empty macro definition
  SET(VXL_USE_WIN_WCHAR_T 0)
ENDIF(WIN32)

# In order to be able to link vxl libraries into shared libraries on 64 bit linux, the -fPIC 
# compiler flag must be added.  Only do this if we are on a x86_64 *nix platform, we're building 
# static libraries, and the user has not explicitly requested position dependent code.
IF(UNIX)
  IF(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "x86_64")
    OPTION(BUILD_POSITION_DEPENDENT_CODE "Generate position dependent code (i.e. code cannot be used in shared library)" OFF)
    MARK_AS_ADVANCED(BUILD_POSITION_DEPENDENT_CODE)
    IF (NOT BUILD_POSITION_DEPENDENT_CODE)
      message(STATUS "Adding -fPIC compiler flag to generate position independent code.")
      SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}-fPIC")
      SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}-fPIC")
    ENDIF(NOT BUILD_POSITION_DEPENDENT_CODE)
  ENDIF(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS AND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR MATCHES "x86_64")
ENDIF(UNIX)

# Build the core vxl + support libraries
SUBDIRS(vcl v3p core)

# Optionally build the contributed libraries
IF( EXISTS ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/CMakeLists.txt )
  OPTION( BUILD_CONTRIB "Build the contributed libraries?" YES )
ENDIF( EXISTS ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/CMakeLists.txt )

IF( BUILD_CONTRIB AND BUILD_CORE_ALL)
  SUBDIRS( contrib )
ENDIF( BUILD_CONTRIB AND BUILD_CORE_ALL)

# Use the old configure script if the cache tells us to do so.
IF(VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)
  IF(RUN_CONFIGURE)
    EXEC_PROGRAM( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/configure
      ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} )
  ENDIF(RUN_CONFIGURE)
ENDIF(VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)

# Some types of path names can cause havoc with regular expressions,
# so avoid those.
IF( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} MATCHES  \\+ )
  MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "You cannot have a + in your binary path")
ENDIF( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} MATCHES  \\+ )
IF( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR} MATCHES  \\+ )
  MESSAGE(SEND_ERROR "You cannot have a + in your source path")
ENDIF( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR} MATCHES  \\+ )

# include CMakeListsLocal.txt from source directory if it exists
# also include it from the binary dir if different from source dir
IF( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} MATCHES ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR} )
  INCLUDE( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeListsLocal.txt OPTIONAL )
ELSE( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} MATCHES ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR} )
  INCLUDE( ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeListsLocal.txt OPTIONAL )
  INCLUDE( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeListsLocal.txt OPTIONAL )
ENDIF( ${vxl_BINARY_DIR} MATCHES ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR} )

# Standard include directories.
SET(VXLCORE_INCLUDE_DIR ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/core ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
SET(VXLCORE_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/vxl/core)
SET(VCL_INCLUDE_DIR ${vxl_BINARY_DIR}/vcl ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/vcl)
SET(VCL_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/vxl/vcl)

# Autoconf does not work on windows.  Use hardcoded results if not using
# cmake to configure.
IF(VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)
  IF(WIN32)
    IF(NOT CYGWIN)
      SET(VCL_INCLUDE_DIR ${vxl_SOURCE_DIR}/vcl/config.win32 ${VCL_INCLUDE_DIR})
      SET(VCL_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR
        ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/vcl/config.win32
        ${VCL_INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}
      )
    ENDIF(NOT CYGWIN)
  ENDIF(WIN32)
ENDIF(VXL_NO_CMAKE_CONFIGURE)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${VCL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${VXLCORE_INCLUDE_DIR})

# This SUBDIRS command must be the last SUBDIRS command in this file
SUBDIRS( config/cmake/export )
```

Comment: How are you referencing it, can you post the CMakeLists.txt? You might need to put it in System / System32.

Comment: @AndyM added CMakeLists.txt

Comment: What compiler are you using, where is the exe? Do you have `which` installed (comes with Cygwin, not sure about MinGW). By looking at those other questions related to that dll, it looks like it needs to be in the same dir as your compiler's exe.

Comment: @AndyM adding C:\MiniGW\bin to my path variable seems to have fixed it, I'm now getting another stack of errors but that's a different pair of sleeves :)